# Testing Laravel View Composers with Mockery

Tags: laravel, mockery

I am trying to test my View Composers. Whenever I pass an object to the `$view->with('string', $object)`, my test fails. This is when I do the test like this:

```
$view
    ->shouldReceive('with')
    ->with('favorites', $this->user->favorites(Ad::class)->get())
    ->once();
```

I'm pretty sure this is due to strict checking. So I looked around and saw [this issue](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/328). However, I can't seem to get it working. The closure return true, but the test fails:

> Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException : Method with('favorites',
>   < Closure===true >) from Mockery_3_Illuminate_View_View should be called
>   exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Here is my current test

```
public function it_passes_favorites_to_the_view()
{
    $this->setUpUser(); // basically sets $this->user to a User object

    Auth::shouldReceive('user')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($this->user);

    $composer = new FavoritesComposer();

    $view = Mockery::spy(View::class);

    $view
        ->shouldReceive('with')
        ->with('favorites', Mockery::on(function($arg) {
            $this->assertEquals($this->user->favorites(Ad::class)->get(), $arg);
        }))
        ->once();

    $composer->compose($view);
}
```

FavoritesComposer class:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $favorites = $user 
        ? $user->favorites(Ad::class)->get()
        : collect([]);

    $view->with('favorites', $favorites);
}
```

How do I test object like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing `$view->with('favorites', $favorites);` with `$view->with(['favorites' => $favorites]);` and then testing it like this:

```
$view
    ->shouldReceive('with')
    ->with(['favorites' => $this->user->favorites(Ad::class)->get()])
    ->once();
```

So, essentially using only one parameter in the `with()`-method is what fixed it for me.